# Kendo UI Grid, computed column

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to make grid with computed column.
My problem is that column is not recomputed when I change the grid.

page(asp.net MVC):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<VistaFlowDTO>()
                  .Name("Grid")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                  columns.Bound(o => o.Country).ClientTemplate("#=model.renderCodeList(Country)#");
                  columns.Bound(o => o.Plant).ClientTemplate("#=model.renderCodeList(Plant)#");
                  columns.Bound(o => o.Flow).Sortable(false).Filterable(false).ClientTemplate("#=model.renderFlow(Flow)#");
                  columns.Bound(o => o.State);
                  columns.Bound(o => o.ConditionStatus).ClientTemplate("#=model.renderCodeList(ConditionStatus)#");
                  columns.Bound(o => o.DateOfUpdate);
                  })
          .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(p => p.Id);
                        model.Field(p => p.Flow).DefaultValue((LeftRightDTO)ViewData["Value"]).Editable(false);
                    })
              .Events(e=> e.Save("model.changeGrid"))
```

javascript:
//template

```
function renderFlow(data) {
            var left = $(data).prop('Left');
            var right = $(data).prop('Right');
            return renderLeftRight(left, right, '_');
        }
function renderLeftRight(left, right, separator) {
            if (!left && !right)
                return '';
            return "<div class='leftAndRight'><span class='left'>" + left + "</span>" + separator + "<span class='right'>" + right + "</span></div>";
        }
```

//called when grid is changed

```
function changeGrid(e) {
       if (e.values.Country || e.values.Plant) {
            var c = e.values.Country || e.model.Country;
            var p = e.values.Plant || e.model.Plant;
            e.model.set("Flow.Left", c);
            e.model.set("Flow.Right", p);
        }
    }
```

Flow (c# class):

```
public class LeftRightDTO
{
    public string Left { get; set; }
    public string Right { get; set; }

    public LeftRightDTO()
    {
    }

    public LeftRightDTO(string left, string right)
    {
        this.Left = left;
        this.Right = right;
    }
}
```

Only working example that i found was this: http://jsfiddle.net/qA8QX/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but in case someone has the same requirement:

You need to refresh the grid once you've changed the model:

```
$("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```